# SQL Server - Update statement with max and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with columns like this but with only the `Salary_ID` column populated:

```
Name: Salary
Salary_ID, TotalAmount
```

I have another SQL Server table with this format and all the columns populated:

```
Name: SalaryImport
Row_ID, Salary_ID, Amount
```

I am trying to update the `Salary` table with the maximum `row_id` for each `salary_id`. Currently, there are many instances of each `Salary_ID` in `SalaryImport` and I only care about the most recent one which is indicated by the higher number `row_id`.

Any tips on how this can be done? I thought I would run a SQL statement like but it is grouping too much (and I can remove amount from the group because it is in the select!):

```
select max(Row_ID), Salary_ID, Amount
from SalaryImport e
group by  Row_ID, Amount
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` query doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 7):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
;with cte as
(
select row_number() over(partition by Salary_ID order by Row_ID desc) as rn,*
From yourtable
)
Update S
Set TotalAmount = c.Amount
From Salary s join cte c on s.Salary_ID = c.Salary_ID
Where RN = 1
```

Comment: I downvoted for duplicating an answer that has been posted hundreds of times to a question that has been posted hundreds of times.   We should be flagging duplicates rather than answering, IMO.

Comment: It's been discussed in Meta.  I don't have a link to the question handy, but a lot of people agree with me.

Comment: Then I would say 90 percnt of the questions asked in SO are duplicates. Should I sit and find the duplicate and mark it as duplicate... instead will one as answer.. will be usefull for OP atleast

Comment: @prdp I appreciate the reply! I search and didn't find it (clearly wasn't wording the search correctly). I appreciate you answering my question and taking the time to solve a problem that I ran into! Thank you!!